# Camera starts in activities where its not needed

Tags: java, android

I have a QR code scanner in my app and the camera stops when my `AlertDialog` is being displayed but restarts as soon as I move to another activity and keeps running in the background even when the app isn't in the foreground.
I have the `stopCamera(`) and `stopCameraPreview()` both but it restarts and stays on as long as the app is open (both foreground and background)
Here's the code for the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
    private ZXingScannerView scannerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(scannerView);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkPermission()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Scanner Active", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                requestPermission();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermission() {
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA);

    }


    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permission, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CAMERA:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (cameraAccepted) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CAMERA)) {
                            displayAlertMessage("You need to allow access for both permsisions",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {


                                                requestPermissions(new String[]{CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkPermission()) {
                if (scannerView == null) {
                    scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
                    setContentView(scannerView);

                }
                scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
                scannerView.startCamera();
            } else {
                requestPermission();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        scannerView.stopCamera();
        scannerView.stopCameraPreview();
    }

    public void displayAlertMessage(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", listener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();

    }

    String[] a = {"ABCD", "PQR"};
    String scanned = "";

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        final String scanResult = result.getText();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (scanResult.equals(a[i])) {
                scanned = a[i];
                scannerView.stopCamera();
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("QR Scan");
                builder.setMessage("Machine Identified!");

                builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, buttons.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);

                        scannerView.stopCameraPreview();

                    }

                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(MainActivity.this);
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
                break;

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: Unrecognized QR Code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(MainActivity.this);

          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

"keeps running in the background even when the app isn't in the foreground" - this is due to the [Activity lifecycle](https://miro.medium.com/max/600/1*Wg3Fq5J35i6NbsGgpDsdow.jpeg). Note that `onDestroy()` is the last method of the `class Activity` that is called and called only when activity is for sure destroyed.

What it means: when you move to the background `onDestroy()` is not called. The activity is still alive and waiting to be resumed. Your activity is still alive and it should be. Use instead of `onDestroy()` method called `onPause()`. You will reach this method if the activity is killed, and it will return back to the `onResume()` when appropriate.

Just overwrite `onDestroy()` to:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    scannerView.stopCamera();
    scannerView.stopCameraPreview();
}
```